# Eliminate 'q' from the text file when user enters q in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have tried creating a text file for asking user names and storing each name in a new line for that file. Now as the user input is being taken unlimited number of times using while loop, I have created a quit option for user to enter 'q' for Quitting.... anytime. After completion of this task when I open the text file 'guest_book.txt' I want to get rid of the ending line, 'q'.

Usually for lists we use the pattern like [elt for elt in filename if elt not in 'q'] which would eliminate that 'q'. How can I accomplish using text files? Any input would be highly appreciated!!!

Here is my code:

```
filename='guest_book.txt'

with open(filename,'a') as file_object:

    while True:
        user_name = input("Enter your name: ")
        file_object.write(user_name)
        file_object.write('\n')
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show how you handle q. Can't you just check for it after input and break the loop before writing it to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to do it is to insert a break

```
while True:
    user_name = input("Enter your name: ")
    if user_name=="q":
        break
    file_object.write(user_name)
    file_object.write('\n')
```

You could do something like

```
user_name=None
while not user_name == "q":
    user_name = input("Enter your name: ")
    file_object.write(user_name)
    file_object.write('\n')
```

But break is probably the best practice here

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
filename='guest_book.txt'

# Edit 1
with open(filename, 'a') as file_object:

    while True:
        user_name = input("Enter your name: ")

        if user_name == 'q':
            break

        else:
            file_object.write(user_name)
            file_object.write('\n')
```

With this code, when it recognize the username as 'q', it would break instantly without writing the 'q' into the file.

Comment: the indentation is broken on your answer. and you don't need to close the file

Comment: Indention fixed, closing the file is just a habit of mine. The main change is the break part.

Comment: That `file_object.close()` part is redundant, it will be done by the `open` content manager anyway.You just need to `break` out of the loop.

Comment: btw, if the user names are to be "added" to the guestbook, the open mode should be 'a', not 'w', otherwise the file will be recreated every time